# Passing library as a paramter in TypeScript and type defining internal module

Tags: typescript

I've started programming in TypeScript and I'm a little befuddled on how to define parameter types under certain circumstances.

Here goes:

::::THE CODE::::

```
// First the references to TypeScript definition files used by the src code
/// <reference path="../lib/express.d.ts"/>;
/// <reference path="../lib/request.d.ts"/>;

// Import modules for the sake of using TypeScript
import express = require('express');
import request = require('request');

var getUuidFromCouchDb = function (httpReq: any, expressRes: express.Response) {
    // Load module/function that parses JSON
    var parseJsonFromRequestWithCheck = require('./parseJsonFromRequestWithCheck');

    // Get a UUID from CouchDB which we can use to create a new document in the database
    httpReq.get('http://127.0.0.1:5984/_uuids', function (httpReqError: any, httpReqRes: any, httpReqBody: any) {
        var resBodyAsJson: JSON = parseJsonFromRequestWithCheck(httpReqBody, expressRes);

        // Do checks on resBodyAsJson
        if (resBodyAsJson && resBodyAsJson.uuids && resBodyAsJson.uuids.length > 0) {
            // UUID in JSON format received from CouchDB - return it to the client
            expressRes.json(resBodyAsJson);
            return;
        } else {
            // Parsing of JSON likely failed in parseJsonFromRequestWithCheck or     malformed data retrieved
            expressRes.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }
    });
}

module.exports = getUuidFromBackend;
```

---

So the questions are:
- I would like to define the type of the "httpReq" parameter to be of "type" "request" library. This might be totally of - if so, what would be the correct way to define a type for that parameter. Using "any" just feels very loose.
- For the variable "parseJsonFromRequestWIthCheck I would also like to define a type for that. It is a module that gives an Express JS response. Either in JSON or by sending a status if, parsing of JSON failed. This with the sendStatus method of the Express JS response. What would be the correct way to do that?

Looking forward to hear from you....

Thank you very much in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to define the type of the "httpReq" parameter to be of "type" "request" library

instead of `httpReq: any` you will have `httpReq: typeof request`.

> For the variable "parseJsonFromRequestWIthCheck I would also like to define a type for that.

Instead of `var parseJsonFromRequestWithCheck` you would have `import parseJsonFromRequestWithCheck`.

To learn more about `import` in TypeScript module system : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KDrWLMUY0R0&hd=1

Comment: Hi basarat - thank you. Saw you vid, get a better mic :-D - the content is fine, but the sound is horrendous.

But good info in your answer. Helped me along. As well as reading the API again.

Thank you.